# How to get country short name from algolia place API from a backend in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, algolia

I have a rails app, and I use algolia places API to autocomplete on my view.
I would like to get the country short name (ISO of two letters) in my rails backend.
Is there a way of calling algolia places API from the backend?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I have my view erb file, which use Algolia js API.
But I don't know how to handle an ask of the api directly from my model in ruby.

Comment: My question can be generalized on how to call an API from a backend and not only from the client side.

Comment: https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-rails

Comment: Why do you need to call it "from the model"? In which moment you need to call it? Do you want to save the call result inside model instance?

Comment: I want to save the country short name. For instance "US".

Comment: Yes, there is in fact not just a way. There are multiple ways.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - use background job for API calling and call the job in the model callback. Or call  API directly from the callback, if you need a result immediately, but in this case every time when the callback runs your app will wait for API response, and only after it the callback is ended.

It is better to find real places inside controllers when you need API calling and do it there, not inside a model.

Long answer - unfortunately, I need more details and your code for such answer :)